# An automatic datagridview filter control (dialog) with filterString property

Tags: c#, winforms, filter

I would like to ask for recommendation of any filter control that I could use to filter Winforms DataGridView. As there are many forms I'd like to use it on, it'd be best if the filter would be created based on what colums are in my DataGridView. The last thing is that I would like to be able to get a kind of filterString like `UserName LIKE 'John' AND Age>21` - I would later use this string to query database table to fetch necessary records. The whole point of all this is that all my DataGridViews present paginated data (e.g. first 200 rows) and I'd like to use this 'filter control' to get from user a string defining what records need to be fetched.

I've already tried Advanced DataGridView and it meets my needs to some extend, but it's quite complex traditional filter (only for data already loaded into DGV) so I really hope there's better solution.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for free controls?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I'm a solo developer not earning on my software and I wouldn't like to lose on it :( What was on your mind, though?